# Google App Engine and Restlet Response differ from localhost

Tags: google-app-engine, restlet

I have a restlet Application on google app engine, when testing on my local machine, I get the normal json response in the form I desire, but when deployed on the live appspot, the response is somehow mixed into some type of object.

localhost:
{"status":"404"}

appspot:
//OK[1,["{\"status\":\"404\"}"],0,7]

Comment: I don't believe I have a "handler", I have my createinboundoute, with the router, then each resource which return string Json objects, please explain.  Thank you

Comment: So I found that on my local server, if I have the org.restlet.ext.gwt.jar in my web-inf, lib folder, the objects are spit out with the ok message and extra brackets, if I remove that jar, the output is normal, however on my deployed version, it is the same with or without that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out,  when declaring @GET, @PUT, @POST, etcc... You need to specify the content type you will be returning, despite the fat that your function may be a String, Rep function, I believe the default is a representation, and that is why the extra junk is added on.  If you simply have @Get("txt") you will get your response as plain text.